# Mocha - Accessing named functions with ti-mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, titanium, mocha.js

I'm using a hybrid version of mocha, [ti-mocha](http://tonylukasavage.com/ti-mocha/), to build unit test for a Titanium SDK-based app. I'm completely new to BDD and mocha, so the API learning curve is quite steep. Here's my issue with a stripped-down test harness. I can access the index.js module, its methods and properties. However, I don't know how to access the named functions, in this case doClick(), within that module.

I'm using mocha + should.js. In the test harness below, context "index" passes, but context "doClick" fails. I'm so new to this API, that I'm not sure if I even framed the question properly. How do I access the functions within the module?

**index-mocha.js**

```
// creates the "mocha" global necessary to run a test suite anywhere in your app
var should = require('should');

module.exports = function(index) {
    // create the test suite
    describe('mochatest', function() {

        context('index', function() {

            it('index exists', function() {
                should.exist(index);
            });

            it('index.open function', function() {
                should(index.open).be.a.Function;
            }); 

            it('id = index', function() {
                index.id.should.equal('index');
            });
        });

        context('doClick', function() {

            it('doClick exists', function() {
                should.exist(index.doClick);
                // return;
            });

            it('doClick is a function', function() {
                should(index.doClick).be.a.Function;
            });
        });
    });

    var outputFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, 'results.json');
    outputFile.createFile();

    mocha.setup({
        reporter: 'ti-spec', // the reporter to use with your tests
        outputFile: outputFile, // write results to the given Ti.Filesystem.File file
        quiet: false // if true, suppress all console logging
    });

    // run the tests
    mocha.run();
    };
```

**index.js**

```
function doClick(e) {
    alert($.label.text);
}

if(runTests){
    require('ti-mocha');

    $.index.addEventListener('open', function(){
        require('index-mocha')($.index);
    });
}

$.index.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see someone playing around with testing in Titanium :)

Just to clarify a thing, the variable `$` refers to an instance of your current controller. Also, **Alloy** gives you references to view elements for which you have defined an id via this variable; This may be seen as a little sugar as all those views are accessible through `$.getViews()`.

Therefore, all functions defined inside your controller file are accessible only from within that controller. If you want them to be accessible from the outside, the easiest and cleanest way is to *exports* them.

This can be done in two ways:

- By directly add them to the controller object

  `$.doClick = doClick;`
- By using the `exports` variable

  `exports.doClick = doClick;`

The result will be exactly the same as, during the compilation, **Alloy** will merge the `exports` variable (which is, initially, only an empty object) with your controller a.k.a `$`.

Then, just pass your controller through your `require` instead of the `index` view, to have access to both views and newly added listeners.

Comment: I was reminded of this shortly after posting this question. doClick() is private and never accessible (doh!). Sometimes, it's the basics that slip past our radar. Thanks for your clarification. As an aside, there is way too little emphasis or support, for that matter, for Titanium unit-testing. It's surprising.